# Flutter Whitelist for pub get

Tags: flutter, whitelist

Currently I have some build servers under corporate policy and need to specify every address to be whitelisted.

I'm having issues with Flutter (pub get)

> pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 7 in 64
> seconds...

I've managed to get some like:
https://pub.dartlang.org

anyone has a complete list of packages and destinations that flutter uses to get data?